# each затирает переменную, выводит только последнее значение

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('table.carttable tbody tr').each(function(){
   td_count = $(this).find('td.carttable-id').attr("valko") + ',';
 });

 console.log(td_count);
```

Выводит только последнее значение, хотя их намного больше. Внутри конструкции поочередно данные выводит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем прицина?

Comment: смотри функцию [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: @Irina Kochenova потому что вы пытаетесь вывести вне тела цикла

Comment: Так и будет, надо плюс добавить
td_count +=

Comment: Всем спасибо)) Надо очки протереть))

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы так написали. Переменная td_count хранит только одно значение.
Вангую, что вы хотели что то такое, но пропустили +:

```
 $('table.carttable tbody tr').each(function(){
   td_count += $(this).find('td.carttable-id').attr("valko") + ',';
 });

 console.log(td_count);
```

Удобнее сделать это так -

```js
let td_count = '';
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table.carttable tbody tr'))
  .forEach(el => {
    td_count += el.querySelector('td.carttable-id').getAttribute("valko") + ',';
});

console.log(td_count);

// Или

const td_count_array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table.carttable tbody tr'))
  .map(el =>   
  el.querySelector('td.carttable-id').getAttribute("valko")
);

console.log(td_count_array.join(','));
```

```html
<table class='carttable'>
<tr>
<td class = 'carttable-id' valko='1'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = 'carttable-id' valko='2'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = 'carttable-id' valko='3'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: для map не нужен `+=`, ты получаешь массив, который объединяется с помощью join и все. и не надо обрезать лишнюю `,`. Плюс, если уже используется `jquery`, то использование нативной функции может неудобнее

Comment: @Grundy сделала с помощью map, спасибо, никогда не пользовалась. ;)

Comment: @Darth вам тоже спасибо, я реально пропустила плюсик, спасибо)